# php spl_autoload_register() wants to load un inexisting class

Tags: php, class, require-once, spl-autoload-register

I’m experiencing a strange behavior with spl_autoload_register(), and I can’t get around it.

I have two web sites; the first is available at http://localhost/website.
It contains a folder dedicated for classes: `document_root/website1/classes/`
in which I wrote some classes, `foo.class.php` and `bar.class.php`.

Each php file on the site (e.g. index.php) loads the classes via this code:

```
function loadTheClasses($classe) {
    require_once('classes/'.$classe.'.class.php');
}
spl_autoload_register('loadTheClasses');
```

The second website is available at http://localhost/website2.
It also contains a folder dedicated for classes `document_root/website2/classes/` in which I wrote the class `bar.class.php`.

Also, each php file on the site (e.g. index.php) loads the classes via this code:

```
function loadTheClasses($classe) {
    require_once('classes/'.$classe.'.class.php');
}
spl_autoload_register('loadTheClasses');
```

In case this may help, please note that files `website1/classes/bar.class.php` and `website2/classes/bar.class.php` are exactly the same files.

Here is the problem :
1 - I first run website1 (website1/index.php)  -> everything works fine
2 - On another tab, I then run website2 (website2/index.php)
On website 2 I get the following errors :

```
Warning: require_once(website2/classes/foo.class.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in website2\index.php on line xx
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'website2/classes/foo.class.php' (include_path='.; php\PEAR') in  website2\index.php on line xx
```

Until I press the F5 function key to reload the page… in that case the errors do not appear anymore.
But if I return to tab website1, and then to tab website2 the errors are rising again ! (until I use the F5 key again)

How can website2 make a call to foo.class.php ? Of course, this class do not exist in website2 ! But why is website2 trying to load it ?

Please help !

Comment: Are you using APC cache?

Comment: And what code is on "line xx"? (From `No such file or directory in website2\index.php on line xx`)

Comment: Also you may place `var_dump($classe)` and `debug_print_backtrace` into `loadTheClasses` function

Comment: No APC Cache. Just using Xamp.
code in line xx is:  require_once('classes/'.$classe.'.class.php');

Comment: What about var_dump and backtrace?

Comment: var_dump($classes) shows me class foo. But I can't see where it could be called. There no point in the code where the foo class is called.
Using debug_print_backtrace() also shows a call to the foo class that does not exist in website2
string(3) "Foo" 
#0 loadTheClasses(Foo) 
#1 spl_autoload_call(Foo)

Comment: debug_print_backtrace should show you lines of code. For example: 
    `php > function foo(){debug_print_backtrace();}
    php > foo();
    #0  foo() called at [php shell code:1]`

Comment: I think I get a hint.
What I did not say is that instances of Foo and Bar are stored into sessions vars in website1, like this :
    $_SESSION['bar'] = new Bar();
    $_SESSION['foo'] = new Foo();
And it seems that website2 reloads session var and ties to access to Foo class... Am i Right ?

Comment: That's It. To solve the problem I just have to give each session a different name eg :
session_name('website1'); in website1
session_name('website2'); in website2
Do you confirm ?

Comment: Sure. It's applicable solution.